# Replace XMLGregorianCalendar via custom binding when using WSDL to Java (wsdl2java)

Tags: soap, binding, jaxb, wsdl2java

My goal is to replace `XMLGregorianCalendar` by a different Java class (e.g. `java.time.LocalDate`).

I'm running `wsdl2java` as part of a maven `pom.xml` file:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
  <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>4.0.2</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>generate-sources</id>
      <phase>generate-sources</phase>
      <configuration>
        <sourceRoot>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/cxf</sourceRoot>
        <wsdlOptions>
          <wsdlOption>
            <wsdl>/path/to/the.wsdl</wsdl>
            <bindingFiles>
              <bindingFile>/path/to/binding.xml</bindingFile>
            </bindingFiles>      
            <extraargs>
              <extraarg>-verbose</extraarg>
            </extraargs>          
          </wsdlOption>
        </wsdlOptions>
      </configuration>
      <goals>
        <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

The binding file looks as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jaxb:bindings xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
               xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
               xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
               jaxb:version="2.1">    
    <jaxb:globalBindings>
      <xjc:javaType name="java.time.LocalDate"
                     xmlType="xs:dateTime"
                     adapter="my.app.LocalDateAdapter" />
    </jaxb:globalBindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

However, the generated Java file still uses `XMLGregorianCalendar` (which is the default class) for `dateTime` XML types:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "SomeType", propOrder = {
    "someDate"
})
public class SomeType {
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "dateTime")
    protected XMLGregorianCalendar someDate;
    ...
}
```

I was expecting the generated Java code to use `java.time.LocalDate` (instead of `XMLGregorianCalendar`) for `dateTime` XML types.

I have seen so many different variations of the binding file but could not get one of them to work. The one binding file mentioned above is the most promising (but obviously wrong) version I came up with.

Although verbose logging is enabled (`<extraarg>-verbose</extraarg>`), none of the wsdl2java log messages indicate an issue in the binding file. Whatever I try, it feels like it is completely ignoring the binding file.

Any idea about what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I found a working solution. It took me a while.

The bindings file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<jaxb:bindings version="3.0"
               xmlns:jaxb="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jaxb"
               xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
               xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <jaxb:globalBindings>
        <xjc:javaType name="java.time.LocalDate"
                      xmlType="xs:dateTime"
                      adapter="my.app.LocalDateAdapter"/>
    </jaxb:globalBindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

The difference with your file is only one line:

- yours: `xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"`
- mine: `xmlns:jaxb="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jaxb"`

Just another namespace.

To confirm this, I posted an example on my [github](https://github.com/elimxim/so-maven-cxf-wsdl-custom-type). Let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: I was upgrading old project and had similar problem. Thanks mate!

Answer (score 0):

**To make sure the generated Java code uses java.time.LocalDate instead of XMLGregorianCalendar for dateTime XML types, you need to configure the cxf-codegen-plugin to use the JAXB binding file during code generation. It seems like the binding file is not being picked up currently. You can modify the configuration of the plugin in your pom.xml as follows:**

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
  <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>4.0.2</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>generate-sources</id>
      <phase>generate-sources</phase>
      <configuration>
        <sourceRoot>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/cxf</sourceRoot>
        <wsdlOptions>
          <wsdlOption>
            <wsdl>/path/to/the.wsdl</wsdl>
            <!-- Add the binding file to the configuration -->
            <bindingFiles>
              <bindingFile>/path/to/binding.xml</bindingFile>
            </bindingFiles>
            <extraargs>
              <extraarg>-verbose</extraarg>
            </extraargs>          
          </wsdlOption>
        </wsdlOptions>
        <!-- Add this configuration to use Java 8 Date/Time API -->
        <defaultOptions>
          <java8>true</java8>
        </defaultOptions>
      </configuration>
      <goals>
        <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
  <!-- Add this configuration to use Java 8 Date/Time API -->
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
      <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

*Make sure to replace /path/to/binding.xml with the actual path to your binding file.*

*With this configuration, the cxf-codegen-plugin should now use the specified binding file during code generation, and the generated Java classes will use java.time.LocalDate instead of XMLGregorianCalendar for dateTime XML types. Additionally, the true option enables the plugin to generate Java 8 Date/Time API classes in the generated code.*

*Remember to have the javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api dependency in your pom.xml to ensure that the Java 8 Date/Time API is used properly.*

Comment: The only difference between the config file in your answer and the one in my question it this:

```
<defaultOptions>
          <java8>true</java8>
</defaultOptions>
```

However, I'm not even able to run it and get this error message:

```
Unable to parse configuration of mojo org.apache.cxf:cxf-codegen-plugin:4.0.2:wsdl2java for parameter java8: Cannot find 'java8' in class 
````

Did I miss anything?

Comment: I also tried using the javax.xml.bind / jaxb-api dependency that you recommended. Unfortunately, it doesn't make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try using parseMethod of jakarta namespace xmlns:jaxb="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jaxb"

<jaxb:globalBindings>
 <jaxb:javaType name="java.util.Date"  xmlType="xs:date" hasNsContext="false"
        parseMethod="com.example.sandbox.jaxb.DateAdapter.parseDate"
        printMethod="com.example.sandbox.jaxb.DateAdapter.printDate"/>
</jaxb:globalBindings>

import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;

public class DateAdapter {
 
    public static Date parseDate(String s) {
        return DatatypeConverter.parseDate(s).getTime();
      }
    
public static String printDate(Date dt) {
        Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
        cal.setTime(dt);
        return DatatypeConverter.printDate(cal);
      } 
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**